# How to install custom packages in Jenkins Docker container?

Tags: python, docker, jenkins

I'm trying to set up a pipeline in a dockerized installation of Jenkins. My pipeline will execute all tests of a python 3.7 project with pytest, and pylint too.

But the official Jenkins Docker image only contains python 2.7 and python 3.5, and neither pylint nor pytest. So I have to install Python 3.7, and pip install pytest and pylint. I'm not used to Docker, so I don't know how to manipulate the container to install packages. I tried `docker exec (...)` but the output is that I don't have the rights.

How can I install all I need in the container ?

Comment: Make your own dockerfile extended from the jenkins one - then you can run any shell command you normally would if you built a standard EC2 baremetal ubuntu install.

Comment: @Trent that seems a good idea. But il the original jenkins image is updated, will my derived image be updated too ?

Comment: @Harkonnen if you rebuild, yes

Comment: yes and no. If you pin it to a specific base image then no, you'll only get updates to that particular image on rebuild, but if you just pin to a very generic base image of jenkins (no major or minor versions) then when you rebuild it will update to the latest.